# Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column

Tags: php, laravel

Migration File

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('progress', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('state_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->foreignId('city_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->text('address');
        $table->string('project_name');
        $table->tinyInteger('status', 2);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

After running php artisan migrate

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a
> key (SQL: create table `progress` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `state_id` bigint unsigned not null, `city_id` bigint
> unsigned not null, `address` text not null, `project_name` varchar(255) not null, `status` tinyint not null auto_increment primary key, `created_a t` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your migration has defined the tiny integer column as an auto increment column. Take a look at the Laravel [tinyInterger](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_tinyInteger) docs and you’ll see the second argument is a Boolean for defining the column as auto increment.

So to remove this error you’ll need to remove the 2 from your column definition.